# Can't Run Package Generated From javafx-basic-archetype

Tags: java, maven, javafx

Following 
https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-basic-archetype
I generated a maven project using:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.zenjava -DarchetypeArtifactId=javafx-basic-archetype
```

Then, I executed `mvn package` from the project directory, and it generated the jar.

I tried to run the jar by double-clicking it, but nothing happens.
I tried to run via command line: `java -jar Tester.jar` but I get the error:

> no main manifest attribute, in target\Tester.jar

Note: it does run from IntelliJIDEA if I import the project and run it, but IntelliJ doesn't generate a `.jar`, only `.class` files.

This is the pom it generates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>testgroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>Tester</artifactId>
    <name>Tester</name>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>testorg</name>
    </organization>

    <properties>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.12</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <build>

        <finalName>Tester</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.5</version>
                <configuration>

                    <mainClass>testgroup.MainApp</mainClass>

                    <!-- only required if signing the jar file -->
                    <keyStoreAlias>example-user</keyStoreAlias>
                    <keyStorePassword>example-password</keyStorePassword>
                    <allPermissions>true</allPermissions>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>

        <!-- MigLayout -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
            <artifactId>miglayout-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging  -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message basically means that you don't have path to your main class specified in Manifest.MF file.

Add to your pom.xml file the following lines of code and change `mainClass` argument for the proper one:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.maventest.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After this you should run `mvn clean package` command and then try to run your application.

Comment: I still get the same error. I added my original pom to the question.

Comment: Could you run 'mvn clean package' commmand with your pom edited like I suggested and paste in comment your Manifest.MF file content?